Computing $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{m-k}{n-k}$ for some arbitrary integer $n$ and with $m \leq n$
My question was: is there a "nice" expression of the following sum (for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\leq n$) :
$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{m-k}{n-k}$
For a bit of context, this came up when trying to compute the expected number of passengers in a bus. The bus starts at stop #1 with 0 passengers, and goes until stop $n$. At each stop, a random number (uniform over {0,...,$N$}, with $N\in\mathbb{N}$) of passengers gets onto the bus and they pick a future stop to get off to, uniformly. The passengers get off when they reach their stop.
The question is then to compute the expected value of the number of passengers at a given stop $m \leq n$.
The result I came up with is :
Expected value at stop $m$ $= \frac{N}{2} (m - \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{m-k}{n-k})$ (note that this only holds for $m<n$, since at stop $m$ no passenger comes on, and in that case if we use m-1 instead of m before the sum, the sum evaluates to 0, which makes sense given our problem)
Which is why I needed to compute that sum.
Thank you for any help!

For clarity, could you explain how we measure the number of passengers at a given stop. e.g. if we have 5 on board before the stop, 2 get off, 4 get on, how many do you count for that stop? Also, when the passengers board, are their future stops independent from each other?

Do you need an exact formula or is an approximation enough? I doubt that this sum can be expressed without a sum or limit.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{m-k}{n-k}=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{m-n+n-k}{n-k}=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\left( \frac{m-n}{n-k}+1\right)=(m-n)\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{n-k} + m-1$$
and the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{n-k}$ can be written in terms of the harmonic numbers $H_n$ as $$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{n-k}= H_{n-1}-H_{n-m}$$
but that last expression can't be further simplified.

I got the same result for the modeling part. Some additional assumptions: everything is independent (and passengers stay at least for one stop in the bus), also $P_{ti}$ is the j-th passenger that got on the bus on time t. Also there is $N_t$ the number of passengers that got on the bus at time t. Then there is a function $\kappa : P_{ti} \to \{t+1,...,n \}$ that tells us when the passenger $P_{ti}$ is going to get of the bus. Now we want to get:
$$
\text{Number of Passengers at time t} = \text{passengers that got on} - \text {passengers that got off before}
$$
or
$$
\sum^m_{t = 1}N_t - \sum_{t = 1}^{m - 1}\sum^{N_t}_{k = 0} \mathbb{1}_{\kappa(P_{tk}) < m} = \sum^m_{t = 1}N_t - \sum_{t = 1}^{m - 1}\sum_{l = 0}^{N} \mathbb{1}_{N_t = l} \sum^{l}_{k = 0} \mathbb{1}_{\kappa(P_{tk}) < m} 
$$
Thus
$$
\mathbb{E}(\text{People on the bus at time m}) = \frac{mN}{2} - \frac{N}{2}\sum_{t = 1}^{m-1}\frac{m-t}{n-t}
$$
Now to your actual question: I think it is very pretty. You can rewrite it as a harmonic series and, as of my knowledge, there is no closed formula for it, so it's quite surely only going to get uglier.
EDIT: I assumed first that $N_t$ was distributed over $\{1,...,N\}$ which is not the case.
